# Flatten nested JSON with pandas.json.normalize()

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm requesting the Shopware 6 API for daily order data including some customer data (name, email) as well as the trackingID(s) and the ordered products that is the productID(s).

I get a response in the form of a nested JSON, for instance something like this:

```
[{'orderNumber': '9500285',
  'orderCustomer': {'email': 'test@test.com',
   'firstName': 'John',
   'apiAlias': 'order_customer'},
  'deliveries': [{'trackingCodes': [12423238472347], 'apiAlias': 'order_delivery'}],
  'lineItems': [{'productId': '0073aa1ebfc684c296f68ea187b09438',
    'apiAlias': 'order_line_item'},
   {'productId': '46ae62ff2398586a235239d1ae675ab4',
    'apiAlias': 'order_line_item'}],
  'apiAlias': 'order'}]
```

or could be also a list of several orders, like so:

```
    [{'orderNumber': '9500285',
  'orderCustomer': {'email': 'test@test.com',
   'firstName': 'John',
   'apiAlias': 'order_customer'},
  'deliveries': [{'trackingCodes': [], 'apiAlias': 'order_delivery'}],
  'lineItems': [{'productId': '0073aa1ebfc684c296f68ea187b09438',
    'apiAlias': 'order_line_item'},
   {'productId': '46ae62ff2398586a235239d1ae675ab4',
    'apiAlias': 'order_line_item'}],
  'apiAlias': 'order'},
 {'orderNumber': '9500273',
  'orderCustomer': {'email': 'test@test.com',
   'firstName': 'Brad',
   'apiAlias': 'order_customer'},
  'deliveries': [{'trackingCodes': ['345345', '44978'],
    'apiAlias': 'order_delivery'}],
  'lineItems': [{'productId': None, 'apiAlias': 'order_line_item'}],
  'apiAlias': 'order'}]
```

What I ideally like to have is a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

| orderNumber | firstName | email | trackingCodes | productIds |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9500285 | John | test@test.com |  | 0073aa1ebfc684c296f68ea187b09438, 46ae62ff2398586a235239d1ae675ab4 |
| 9500273 | Brad | test@test.com | 345345, 44978 |  |

The trackingCodes can have several or none entries, as well as the productIds

I was able to get so far with the pandas `json_normalize` function:

```
df_track = pd.json_normalize(order_data, ["deliveries"], ["orderNumber", ["orderCustomer", "email"], ["orderCustomer", "firstName"]], errors='ignore')
```

which gives me

| trackingCodes | apiAlias | orderNumber | orderCustomer.email | orderCustomer.firstName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [12423238472347] | order_delivery | 9500285 | test@test.de | John |

When I'm trying to add `lineItems` for a json response of 1 order, like so:

```
df_track = pd.json_normalize(order_data, ["deliveries"], ["orderNumber", "lineItems", ["orderCustomer", "email"], ["orderCustomer", "firstName"]], errors='ignore')
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Length of values (2) does not match length of index (1)
```

Any idea how to make the `json_normalize` function of pandas more flexible and independent of entries of the json response?

Comment: Just ignore json_normalize, step through the json result manually, write a for-loop to handle it, format it accordingly (e.g., a list of dicts or a dict of lists), and turn that into a dataframe. Not everything has to be a one-line-converts-all-into-adataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pd.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to concatenate two dataframe

```
df_track = pd.json_normalize(order_data, ["deliveries"], ["orderNumber", ["orderCustomer", "email"], ["orderCustomer", "firstName"]], errors='ignore')

df_track2 = pd.json_normalize(order_data, record_path=['lineItems'])

df_new = pd.concat([df_track,df_track2], axis=0)

df_new.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

print(df_new)
```